# How to add suffix in Google Charts callback? Formatter not working

Tags: callback, google-visualization, suffix

I can't figure out how to get a callback to work in Google Charts to include a suffix or prefix using the formatter function.  Only need the data to work in tooltip. I might be missing something in the wpDataChartsCallbacks, but the rest of the functionality is fine...

tried obj.options.formatter
tried obj.options.tooltip = formatter:

Can't figure out any workaround...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function(){ 
if( typeof wpDataChartsCallbacks == 'undefined' ){ wpDataChartsCallbacks 
= {}; } 
wpDataChartsCallbacks[5] = function(obj){ 
obj.options.backgroundColor = ''; 
obj.options.vAxis = {textPosition: 'none'};
obj.options.formatter = new 
google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern:'###.# %'});
formatter.format(data,1);
};
</script>
```

Just want to add a suffix or prefix to each.  Everything else works well functionally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the formatter is being created as --> `obj.options.formatter`

but trying to be used as --> `formatter.format`

try using the full namespace --> `obj.options.formatter.format(data,1);`

assuming `data` is within scope...

Comment: Thanks.  Decided to stick with HighCharts and am trying to figure out the comma issue there.  I will be back with that question soon!  But your info was spot on!